# Find a Basis for $V$ if we know a basis for $V^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to find a basis for a subspace $V$, but i know that: {$(1,2,-1,0),(0,2,1,3)$} is basis of $V^\perp $. 
For this, i have the following theorem: Let $A$ a matrix, then we have:

$1.$ $Row(A)^\perp$ $=$ $Null(A)$

So, my arguement is this: $Null(A) = Row(A)^\perp$, and $Row(A) = V$, we have that $Null(A)^\perp = (Row(A)^\perp)^\perp)$ but $(Row(A)^\perp)^\perp) = Row(A) = V$, so if we apply this theorem to $Null(A)^\perp$ we must be find a basis for $V$, but it doesn't works.

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: What if $Row(A)=V^\perp$?

Comment: $Row(A)$ is is the subspace generated by the file vectors of A, in spanish is $Fil(A)$ the notation is wrong?

Comment: You asked for help. That was a hint. Try your reasoning again starting from that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by $Row$... However, one has $(Im\,A)^\perp = \ker A^T$. So put your vectors as columns into a matrix $A$. Then you know that $Im\,A = V^\perp$. Equivalently, $(Im\,A)^\perp = V$. So, $V = \ker A^T$. So, you have to find $\ker A^T$.

Comment: $Row(A)$ is is the subspace generated by the file vectors of A, in spanish is $Fil(A)$ the notation is wrong?

Comment: It's the _row_ vectors in English. But yeah, I've never seen it before.